# How do I get xhtml2pdf working on GAE?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, app.yaml, xhtml2pdf

I am new to GAE, web dev and python, but am working my way up.

I have been trying to get xhtml2pdf working on GAE for some time now but have had no luck.  I have downloaded  various packages but keep getting errors of missing modules. These errors vary depending on what versions of these packages and dependencies I use. I have even tried using the xhtml2pdf "required dependency" versions.

I know xhtml2pdf used to be hosted on GAE according to a stackoverflow post from 2010, but I don't know if this is the case anymore. Have they replaced it with something else that the GAE team think is better?

I have also considered that the app.yaml is preventing my app from running. As soon as I try importing the pisca module, my app stops.

Could anyone please give me some direction on how to get this working? In the sense of how to install these packages with dependencies and where they should be placed in my project folder (note that I am using Windows). And what settings I would need to add to my app.yaml file.

Answer (score 0):

I got it now!  Don't use XHTML2PDF - use ReportLab on its own instead.